# Embedding python serial controller in C++

Tags: python, c++, interface, serial-port

I've been searching around for several hours trying to get this code working and I just can't quite seem to get it.

I'm working on a function in C++ where I can call one of a number of python scripts, which have variable numbers of arguements. The Python works, but I keep getting segfaults in my C++.

```
  double run_python(motor_command command){
    //A routine that will run a python function that is in the same directory.
    Py_Initialize();
    PySys_SetPath(".");
    string pyName; //Declaration of the string and int
    int speed;
    if (command.action == READ){
        pyName = "read_encoders"; //Name of one python module
    }else{
        pyName = "drive_motor"; //Name of the other python module
        speed = command.speed;  //struct
    }

    int board_address = command.board_address;
    int motor = command.motor_num;

    //PyObject* moduleName = PyString_FromString(pyName.c_str()); 
    //  Py_INCREF(myModule);
    //PyObject* myFunction = PyObject_GetAttrString(myModule, "run"); //Both of these python functions have subroutine 'run'

    PyObject* args;
    if(command.action == READ){
        args = PyTuple_Pack(2,PyInt_FromLong(board_address),PyInt_FromLong(motor)); //Appropriate args for the read_encoders
    }else{
        args = PyTuple_Pack(3,PyInt_FromLong(board_address),PyInt_FromLong(motor), PyInt_FromLong(speed)); //Appropriate args for the drive_motor
        }
    Py_INCREF(args);
    cout << "I got here" << endl;
    PyObject* myModule = PyImport_Import((char*)pyName.c_str());//Python interface
    cout << "args = " << args << " modlue = " << myModule << endl;
    //Py_INCREF(myModule);
    PyObject* myResult = PyObject_CallObject(myModule, args); //Run it and store the result in myResult
    Py_INCREF(myResult);

    double result = PyFloat_AsDouble(myResult);
    Py_DECREF(myResult);

    return result;

}
```

So far, what I can figure out is that somehow my myModule is not geting imported correctly and is returning a NULL value. As a result, when I attempt the _CallObject, it throws a segfault and I'm up a creek. When I uncommend the Py_INCREF for myModule, it throws a segfault there, and so I guess taht I'm not importing my python code correctly.

Oh, useful information: OS: Angstorm Linux, on a MinnowBoard (x86 architecture).

General structure of the python program:

```
import sys
import serial

board_num = sys.argv[1]
motor = sys.argv[2]
speed = sys.argv[3]


def run(board_num, motor, speed):
    # Command arguments: Board number (0x80, 0x81...), motor number (0 or 1) and speed(2's complement signed integer)

    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyPCH1', 38400)

    motor_min = 0
    motor_max = 1 # These are the two acceptable values for motor enumerated values. 
    e_code = -1 # Error code

    try:
        board_num = int(board_num, 0)
    except:
        print "Invalid address format: Must be a number"
        exit(e_code)
    try:
        motor = int(motor, 0)
    except:
        print "Motor must be either motor 0 or 1. Or possibly one or two..."
        exit(e_code)
    try:
        speed = int(speed, 0)
    except:
        print "Motor speed must be an integer."
        exit(e_code)

    #print board_num
```

Thank you in advance! If you have any alternative ways to get this working in the same way, I'm open for suggestions!

Comment: An alternative way, you say? Well ... Dropping the C++ bit might solve the problem. Why don't you implement this in Python only?

Comment: Haha, I wish. It's a design requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to append . to your sys.path:

```
PyObject *sys_path; 
PyObject *path; 

sys_path = PySys_GetObject("path"); 
path = PyString_FromString(".") 
if (PyList_Append(sys_path, path) < 0)
```

source: http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/dev/675857

OLD:
First try to execute your Python script alone, with python on the command line.
It is harder to debug Python errors from a C/C++ program. Did you install pySerial?

Comment: As mentioned in the question, yes, the python works flawlessly by itself, including pySerial.

Comment: I think the problem is on PySys_SetPath("."); I think it clears your module path. I'm checking the docs...